# Python: Reading UTF - 8 from raw_input() & Writing UTF - 8 in file

Tags: python, file, utf-8

So, i would like to make a program does 2 things:

1. Reads A Word
2. Reads the translation in Greek

Then I make a new format that looks like this: `"word,translation"` and i'm  writing it into a file.

So the test.txt file should contain `"Hello,Γεια"` and in case i read again , the next line should go under this one.

```
word=raw_input("Word:\n")  #The Word
translation=raw_input("Translation:\n").decode("utf-8") #The Translation in UTF-8
format=word+","+translation+"\n"
file=open("dict.txt","w")
file.write(format.encode("utf-8"))
file.close()
```

The Error I get:

> UnicodeDecodeError 'utf8'codec can't decode byte 0x82 in position 0: invalid start byte

**EDIT**: This is Python 22

Comment: Add the full error message so we see which line has the problem. Are you on windows? What is `sys.getdefaultencoding()`. And considering that poor unicode support was one reason python 3 was invented, why in the world implement this in crappy old python 2?!

Comment: You should probably move to Python 3, which has much better support for Unicode.

Comment: Oh, and what is `sys.stdin.encoding`? You may want to do `raw_input(..).decode(sys.stdin.encoding)` to get it to work.

Comment: the sys.getdefaultencoding() is ascii , my laptop for some reason can't run python 3,running py 3  can fix the problem?

Comment: raw_input(..).decode(sys.stdin.encoding) solved the problem , thanks a lot for all of your replies!

Comment: Your first challenge is figuring out the encoding coming from stdin. Python 3 does that for you. I think my tip to use sys.stdin.encoding will help. How about doing `print repr(raw_input())` then input the greek stuff and post what's printed here. Then we can try some encodings to see what sticks.

Comment: It worked? Great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although python 2 supports unicode, its input is not automatically decoded into unicode for you. `raw_input` returns a string and if something other than ascii is piped in, you get the encoded bytes. The trick is to figure out what that encoding is. And that depends on whatever is pumping data into the program. if its a terminal, then `sys.stdin.encoding` should tell you what encoding to use. If its piped in from, say, a file, then `sys.stdin.encoding` is None and you just kinda have to know what it is.

A solution to your problem follows. Note that even though your method of writing the file (encode then write) works, the `codecs` module imports a file object that does it for you.

```
import sys
import codecs

# just randomly picking an encoding.... a command line param may be
# useful if you want to get input from files
_stdin_encoding = sys.stdin.encoding or 'utf-8'

def unicode_input(prompt):
    return raw_input(prompt).decode(_stdin_encoding)

word=unicode_input("Word:\n")  #The Word
translation=unicode_input("Translation:\n")
format=word+","+translation+"\n"
with codecs.open("dict.txt","w") as myfile:
    myfile.write(format)
```